# Combining the results of multiple select statements.

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

The Access Database I have is a large single table - the design is more like a spreadsheet than a database. I'm trying to get the yield for the 3 different component items out of it.

I've come up with queries to get my failures and opportunities for failure values for each item. Calculating each of these values requires it's own separate where clause - it's not as simple as summing a column unfortunately. So I'm trying to come up with a way to calculate the yield from using the results of each of those queries and then union them together. Here's a pseudo example:

```
Select "Component 1", ((t1.OpForFails - IIf(t2.GenuineFails IS NULL, 0,t2.GenuineFails)) * 100.0) / t1.OpForFails as Yield FROM t1 and t2

UNION 

Select "Component 2", ((t3.OpForFails - IIf(t4.GenuineFails IS NULL, 0,t4.GenuineFails)) * 100.0) / t3.OpForFails as Yield FROM t3 and t4

UNION 

Select "Component 3", ((t5.OpForFails - IIf(t6.GenuineFails IS NULL, 0,t6.GenuineFails)) * 100.0) / t5.OpForFails as Yield FROM t5 and t6
```

Giving me an output like:

```
Component 1      81
Component 2      94
Component 3      77
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `UNION ALL` and make sure you have the same number and type of columns in selects.

[Here is the full article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/combine-the-results-of-several-select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-HA010206109.aspx)